# How to assert if an action creator has been called from a redux connected container component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, enzyme, redux-thunk

I've tried various ways but I can't seem to find anything about specifically testing if an action creator is called from a component. The hard part seems to be getting enzyme and redux connected containers to work. Below I'm exporting both connected and component class for tests. I tried wrapping the connected one in a provider but then I don't know how to target the textarea from enzyme to trigger the simulated onChange. The below works but I'm not sure if it's the best way of doing this?

**Simple container:**

**I want to assert that onChange will call sendCommandValueChange with the correct value.**

```
import React, { Component }  from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'; 
import { sendCommandValueChange } from 'actions';

export class RobotCommand extends Component {
  handleCommandChange(e){
    this.props.sendCommandValueChange(e.target.value);
  }
  render(){ 
    return (
      <div>
        <textarea 
          onChange={ e => this.handleCommandChange(e)}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(null, { sendCommandValueChange })(RobotCommand);
```

**and here is the test:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
import { RobotCommand } from './RobotCommand';

describe('RobotCommand', () => {

  it('should call sendCommandValueChange action creator on value change', () => {
    const props = { sendCommandValueChange: sinon.spy() };
    const wrapper = shallow(<RobotCommand {...props} />);
    wrapper.find('textarea').simulate('change', {target: {value: 'foo'}});
    expect(props.sendCommandValueChange.calledWith('foo')).to.equal(true);
  });

});
```

Comment: Looks good to me. You can also use something like `mockStore` but this is good, better even, because you're encapsulating logic